# Issue with reactive nested flatMap calls

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I need to perform an operation on two `Monos`. **The difficulty is that one depend on the result of the other.**

Let me explain:

- I have a `Mono<User>` (I get that from a `ServerRequest`; `User` is a POJO).
- I need to be able to extract the user email from the above `Mono` and pass it to the `UserRepository` in order to check whether the email already exists in DB.
- If the user already exists I will throw a `400` error; otherwise, I will save the user contained in the `ServerRequest`.

Here is what I have tried in my `handler`:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> saveUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class)
        .flatMap(user -> userRepository
            .findByEmail(user.getEmail())
            .flatMap(foundUser -> {
                if (foundUser != null) {
                    System.out.println("found:" + foundUser);
                    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Email already exists");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("creating" + user);
                    return status(CREATED).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(userRepository.save(user), User.class);
                }
            }));
}
```

`User`:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String firstName;
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String lastName;
    @Email
    private String email;
}
```

`UserRepository`:

```
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("select id, first_name, last_name, email from user u where u.email = :email")
    Mono<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

However, It seems there's an issue with my subscription: none of my `System.out.println` are called when the endpoint is called. Can someone please help?

**edit 1**: Here is the `router` calling the above `handler` method:

```
@Configuration
public class UserRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(UserHandler userHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route()
            .GET("/api/user", accept(APPLICATION_JSON), userHandler::getUsers)
            .POST("/api/sign-up", accept(APPLICATION_JSON), userHandler::saveUser)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on what is the issue? you see error or incorrect result?

Comment: Hello Martin. The issue is that none of my `System.out.println` are called.

Comment: I see. I will have a chance to write an answer for your problem in an hour.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: Have you explicitly checked the case when a `User` does exist? I suspect, the issue is in the `foundUser == null` test since `foundUser` can not be `null`

Comment: Hello caco3. Thanks for your comment. What do you mean by `found == null`?

Comment: I mean that this condition is never `true` (`Mono` is not allowed to emit `null`). The `Mono` returned by the repository will be [`Mono.empty`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#empty--) if the `User` does not exist. To handle the absence of a `User` you can use the [`switchIfEmpty`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#switchIfEmpty-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) operator

Comment: I see. Your point is interesting. However on first call the DB is empty and this `System.out.println("creating" + user);` should be called. What are your thoughts? That is why I think there is an issue with my subscription not completing.

Comment: Try @MartinTarjányi 's solution. It should work:)

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I understand better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you expect a null when the user is not found, however, in reactive streams null is invalid. Instead, reactive streams have a dedicated empty state and dedicated operators to handle the empty case.

In your example you could do the following:

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> saveUser(ServerRequest serverRequest)
{
    return serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class)
                        .flatMap(this::createUserIfNotExists);
}

private Mono<ServerResponse> createUserIfNotExists(User user)
{
    return userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail())
                         .hasElement()
                         .flatMap(foundUser ->
                         {
                             if (foundUser)
                             {
                                 System.out.println("found user");
                                 throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                                         "Email already exists");
                             } else
                             {
                                 System.out.println("creating user");
                                 return status(CREATED).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                       .body(userRepository.save(user), User.class);
                             }
                         });
}
```

or another alternative:

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> saveUser(ServerRequest serverRequest)
{
    return serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class)
                        .flatMap(this::createUserIfNotExists);
}

private Mono<ServerResponse> createUserIfNotExists(User user)
{
    return userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail())
                         .flatMap(foundUser ->
                                 status(BAD_REQUEST)
                                         .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                                         .body(BodyInserters.fromObject("User already exists."))
                         )
                         .switchIfEmpty(
                                 userRepository.save(user)
                                               .flatMap(newUser -> status(CREATED).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                                                  .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(newUser)))
                         );
}
```